# DD claiming to write to SD card, not doing anything

Tags: sd-card, image

I'm running into an issue where if I attempt to flash a microSD card with

`sudo dd bs=4M if=some_pi_image.img of=/dev/sdb`

It claims to have written the image at about 1.9 GB/s, with output:

`1088+0 records in
1088+0 records out
4563402752 bytes (4.6 GB) copied, 2.59837 s, 1.8 GB/s`

But has definitely not written to the card.

Stranger still, when I run "sync" after the dd command it returns pretty much immediately.  However it's verifiable that when I put the SD card in my pi and boot it up, it's running the old image, and essentially has flashed nothing to the card.  I'm careful to umount all /dev/sdbX partitions before running the dd command.

Just for grins I took the microSD card out of the adapter and ran DD again, and got the exact same result, though I know "sdb" is the correct designation, as i can unplug the usb adapter and /dev/sdb will stop showing up when I run "ls /dev/".

I've tried this across 2 cards (one that came with the pi, raspberry symbol and all) and 3 adapters.  Running Ubuntu.

Why would "sync" be returning immediately, and nothing be written to the actual SD card?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi. Please, what is your question?

Comment: Edited to explicitly ask the question :D

Comment: I'm using dd regularly and never encountered anything like it. Nothing seems to suggest that copying from `some_pi_image.img` to `/dev/sdb` produced an error, except that your SD-card doesn't show the data you expect. I don't use `sync` at all so I don't know how long it should take to finish after a big copy job. I'm unsure how one would reproduce your problem...

Comment: have a look at the output of `dmesg` or the log file `/var/log/syslog`, I would guess that your uSD card is locked or gone bad, or your adapter supplies multiple /dev/sd? entries, and you're not accessing the correct one.  See output of `sudo fdisk -l` to find uSD card.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this problem and it turned out to be a faulty sd card.  I tried to delete partitions and reformat the sd card but it plain refused.  Use another sd card and it was fine.

Comment: I've also seen this happen once, though I forget the brand of the card. A new card worked fine.

Answer (score 11):

Late to the party, but I had the same issue today:

```
$ sudo dd if=output/images/sdcard.img of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=2M status=progress
66+1 records in
66+1 records out
138412544 bytes (138 MB, 132 MiB) copied, 0.0644025 s, 2.1 GB/s
```

As it turns out, sometimes the device file `/dev/mmcblk0` does not get deleted when the SD card is removed, and when the device is plugged in, it is not updated as such and no other `/dev/mmcblk` file is created; I have not yet found the root cause for this.  This meant that the `dd` command was simply firing data at a file not tied to a device.

I removed the card, deleted `/dev/mmcblk0` by hand (`rm /dev/mmcblk0`), and re-inserted it.  The card was now functioning.  So I would caution anyone immediately jumping to the conclusion of a bad SD card.  If this issue is occurring, `/dev/mmcblk0` will persist *after* the card is unplugged.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a misunderstanding.  That dev node is not hardwired to the physical slot on your computer.  If it persists after you remove the card and you then re-insert it, the card will now be, e.g., `mmcblk1` (vs. `0`).  A device is an abstract concept, so "firing data at a file not tied to a device" might be better phrased, "firing data at *the wrong* device", *wrong* meaning not the one you thought it was.  *"...deleted /dev/mmcblk0..."* -> In future don't do that.

Comment: I checked for existence of other `/dev/mmcblk` files though and there were no others, the partition device files `/dev/mmcblk0p1`, `/dev/mmcblk0p2` were always created in the same place as well, however they disappeared when the SD card was removed.

Comment: My `dmesg` output while this was occurring: 

`[429752.591765] mmc0: card aaaa removed
[429756.825526] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address aaaa
[429756.826103] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SL16G 14.8 GiB 
[429756.828492]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
`

Comment: What does "I deleted `/dev/mmcblk0` by hand" mean? Without a command or some type of hint, this answer is not useful to anyone who doesn't already know how to do everything you suggested.

Comment: You really think someone who's using `dd` doesn't know how to use `rm`? Updated the answer anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem with this:

```
dd bs=4M if=2018-04-18-raspbian-stretch.img of=/dev/sdX conv=fsync
```

But it worked by dropping the `fsync`

```
dd bs=4M if=2018-04-18-raspbian-stretch.img of=/dev/sdX
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. In addition, I found out that removing the old partitions on the SD card using `fdisk` did not do anything either, which is a quicker test than trying `dd` again. I was able to create a file using `touch this_is_partX` in the root of each mounted partition on the SD card, which is useful to check 1) if the SD card is still functional and writeable, and 2) if a subsequent reinstall of the pi image actually worked and overwrote these files.

The fix turned out to **reboot the linux pc** used for installing the image to the SD card. After the reboot, the `dd` command took about twice the time, and really wrote a fresh image on the SD card.

Answer (score 0):

One more option to consider, is that to make sure you have the device name correct.  For example I discovered I was doing `dd of=/dev/mmblk0` which was showing files data written to that location.  However, I finally noticed that the device path was /dev/mm**c**blk0.